# How to add a DIV next to a centralized INPUT box without skewing the input box

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a form and in that form I have a table and only one row and a TD that centralizes anything in it. I have a empty DIV next to it which I use as a WARNING in case the INPUT box is empty when they leave the INPUT box:

```
<td align="center" >Ange din bokningskod: <input id="bokningskod" type="text" name="bokningskod" autofocus="true" maxlength="8" size="10" onblur="bookingNotEmpty();" /> <div id="alertB" ></div></td >
```

The JavaScript function looks like this:

```
function bookingNotEmpty()
{
    if (document.getElementById("bokningskod").value == "") {
        document.getElementById('alertB').innerHTML = "<< Kan ej vara tomt!";
        document.getElementById("bokningskod").focus();
        return false;
        }
    document.getElementById('alertB').innerHTML = "";
}
```

What is my problem?

If the INPUT box is left empty, the text is added in the DIV, but that moves the INPUT box to the left due to it is centralized.

Can I by some means make the INPUT box remain centralized even though I add text in the DIV?

Thanks in advance!

//Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#alertB {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/6YyGM/)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer @Tamil but it did not solve my issue.

Comment: @Andreas: Did you tried that fiddle? You can update it to show your exact problem.

Comment: No, I did not check the fiddle, will do so!

Answer (score 0):

Just position the div `absolute` so that it takes it out of the flow, you could also just apply a `float:right` to the alert div.

```
<td align="center" class="inputalert" >
    Ange din bokningskod: 
    <input id="bokningskod" type="text" name="bokningskod" autofocus="true" maxlength="8" size="10" onblur="bookingNotEmpty();" /> 
    <div class="alertdiv" id="alertB" ></div>
</td >
```

CSS

```
.inputalert {
    position:relative; //needed to keep the div in the td
}

.inputalert .alertdiv {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

OR

```
.inputalert .alertdiv {
    float:right;
}
```

You could also just put the alert div in another td so it shows up to the side

```
<td align="center" class="inputalert" >
    Ange din bokningskod: 
    <input id="bokningskod" type="text" name="bokningskod" autofocus="true" maxlength="8" size="10" onblur="bookingNotEmpty();" /> 
</td >
<td>
    <div class="alertdiv" id="alertB" ></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Do I have to use CLASS? Can I not continue with ID even in the CSS?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. In the first case, the DIV appeared in the center mixed with the text (on top or behind, not sure). In the second suggestion the div occurred beneath the INPUT box.

Comment: You could use the ID but that would be only for that single one, i used a class in case you were planning on doing it with other input / div combinations.  As for the overlap you will have to adjust the size of the column/table width. it has to be big enough to accommodate the text, the input box and the div and its text, you have to do this even if you had them all laid out normally.

Comment: Also editing to add a second column this will let the input be in its own column and the alert div in the one next to it

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is that the div is breaking onto the next line? If this is the case then you need to make the div inline. By default it is block;

```
yourDiv { display: inline };
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXypM/

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out and report back.